# akka actor model vs java usage in following scenario

Tags: performance, scala, scalability, akka

I want to know the applicability of the Akka Actor model.

I know it is useful in the case a huge number of Actor instances are created and destroyed. e.g. a call server, where every incoming call creates an actor instance and communicates with few other actors and get killed after the call is over.

*Is it also useful in the following scenario :*

A server has a few processing elements (10~50) implemented over Actors. The lifetime of these processing elements is infinite. some of them do not maintain state and a few maintain state. The processing elements process the message and pass the message to other actors in a fixed manner. The system receives a huge number of messages from outside and gets passed through processing elements and goes out of the system.

My gut feeling is that we cannot get any advantage by using Akka Actor model and even implementing this server in Scala. Because the use case for which Akka is designed, is not applicable here. If the scale-up meant that processing elements be increased dynamically then it would be applicable.

For fixed topologies, I think if i implement it in Java, it is going to be more beneficial in terms of raw performance. The 'immutability' feature of Scala leads to more copies and so reduces performance. So i believe i better stick to Java.

Is my understanding correct? I a nut shell i want to know why i should leave Java and use Scala/Akka for the application scenario above. and my target is to process 1 million messages per second.

Comment: I think this is an excellent use-case for Akka. Processing units, some stateful, all exchanging messages. Why wouldn't you use it ? There is no reason Akka wouldn't work well for fixed actor topologies.

Comment: Same as above. The fact that the actors has unbounded lifetime has nothing to do with the applicability of Akka here. In fact, most pipeline style processing tasks -- which your case looks like -- are an excellent match.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I missed it in my question, but what i want to say is that for fixed topologies what is the advantage of Akka actor model over same thing implemented in Java. Finally Scala uses Java data structures fr queue etc. So i think Java will give me more raw performance. If that is the case, then why should anyone consider Scala for raw performance?

Comment: I'm not sure you're right about Actor instances being created and destroyed. Each akka actor instance is created once and is alive until you explicitly kill it with a specific message or until it fails with some error and its supervisor strategy doesn't spawn it back.

Comment: thanks for clarification. my main question is Scala vs Java for the above scenario. If Scala, why?

Comment: You could use Java or Scala for processing 1M msgs/sec and I would hazard a bet you wouldn't see much a performance difference with either. I'm running a Scala/Akka setup at the moment with 60 Actors (most with static lifetimes in a round-robin scheduler) processing ~500K msg/sec with a lot of room to grow; for me, the decision to use Scala was a case of reduced time to deployment -- fewer bugs! less code! -- and lower on-going maintenance costs.

Comment: Thanks. I ran a prototype in my i5 4 core CPU and i am not able to go beyond roughly 800K per second, but this is just a prototype application with a simple Message. The Java implementation also gives same performance.

Comment: If we're talking about using akka from scala/java, a comparison won't make any substantial difference. I'm assuming that you're evaluating akka vs. a custom multi-threaded java solution. Otherwise I would stress out that actor's topologies in akka are fixed, just as per your requirement, and that they're very efficient at their work. Actual implementation of single actors in scala/java is almost indifferent to me, since any java code can be implemented just as efficiently in scala using imperative style.

Comment: you are right. i am comparing Scala Akka and custom MT Java solution. Both give me same performance when i tested. I was thinking that Scala will give less performance. but it is not so.

Answer (score 2):

If this question is still actual...

1. Scala vs. Java

   - Scala gives productivity to developers.
   - Immutability decreases debugging to almost zero level.
   - GC perfectly copes with waste immutables.
2. Akka Actors vs. other means

   - Akka has dispatcher that distributes all tasks across fixed thread pool. This allows to evenly consume available resources. This approach is much better than the fixed worker threads — the processing resources are provided to the tasks not DataFlow nodes.
3. DataFlow implementation

   - There is a [SynapseGrid](https://github.com/Primetalk/SynapseGrid/) library that is built on top of Akka Actors and allows easy construction of DataFlow systems distributed over fixed immortal Actors. It can even draw the DataFlow diagram (in [.dot format](http://www.graphviz.org/)) of the whole system.
     (The library is more convenient to be used with Scala.)